# Errors with cocoapods: unable to add a source

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

On a new Mac (Mojave 10.14.1), I am trying to get cocoapods to work in a project. If I uninstall cocoapods `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods`, and `rm -rf ~/.cocoapods`, and then install it again `sudo gem install cocoapods`, the command `pod install` works as intended.

But if I run `pod install' again, I get the error:

```
[!] Unable to add a source with url `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` named `master-1`.
You can try adding it manually in `~/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.
```

I have updated git (from `2.17.2 (Apple Git-113)` to `2.19.2`); checked that `~/.cocoapods/master` exists; checked the `Command Line Tools` in Xcode preferences; tried `sudo xcode-select -r`; but none of these solutions work for me.

Comment: Did you try these: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4293?

Comment: @gagarwal Yes, I believe I did, unless there's some subtlety I missed!

Comment: I've been getting a warning about the casing of the source URL recently during updates.  Had to change it to lowercase `https://github.com/cocoapods/specs.git` but I doubt that's your issue.  In case it helps though

Answer (score 0):

The problem was an antivirus software installed on my computer (by the IT department at my new job). The software blocked `/bin/sh` from running, which caused that error. We removed the antivirus software, and things now work as they should.

I'll keep this question here, in case the same situation arises for someone else.